# Stripe Connect With Apple Pay iOS

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, applepay

In a restaurant [Pickup Point] you purchase food it comes in a Tiffin Box [Product] which is having a cost[$1].
As you take that box your time starts , You have to submit that box [In Drop Box] in a certain time [Ex:- Within 24 hour].

If you submit the Tiffin box within >24 hr then no charges will deduct from your Apple Pay.

If you exceed the time limit [<24 hr] of submitting the box then automatically $1 will deduct from your Apple Pay.

Note:- Is this facility/Functionality supported by Apple Pay, If yes then how can we achieve this.
"Every reply will be greatly appreciated."

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use [auth and capture](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later) and auth the meal cost + the Tiffin Box cost, and then either capture only the meal cost or the total of both, depending on dropoff.

Otherwise, you could do same for just the Tiffin Box charge.

Also this has nothing to do with Apple Pay specifically; it's just a payment, so it's really a server-side integration question.